# Do a simple calculation in word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have many documents i need to edit, i have the Version of the document in the Header like "Version #" these documents have different versions, but are all a single integer value. These versions need to +1 so i need to get the number then just add 1 then save.

This is seeming pretty tricky and im not sure its possible. Any Help would be appreciated.

For example.
**Old Document**
    "Version 2"
**New Edit**
    "Version 3"

I can find and replace as i have learned from [here](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/4054-replace-text-multiple-documents.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub UpdateVersions()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String
Dim wdDoc As Document, wdSctn As Section, wdHdFt As HeaderFooter
strDocNm = ActiveDocument.FullName
strFolder = GetFolder: If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With wdDoc
      For Each wdSctn In .Sections
        With wdSctn
          For Each wdHdFt In .Headers
            With wdHdFt
              If .LinkToPrevious = False Then
                With .Range
                  With .Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                    .Text = "Version [0-9]{1,}"
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Format = False
                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                    .Execute
                  End With
                  Do While .Find.Found = True
                    .Text = "Version " & Split(.Text, " ")(1) + 1
                    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    .Find.Execute
                  Loop
                End With
              End If
            End With
          Next
        End With
      Next
      .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
  End If
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick hack that may do what you wish.

First of all, make sure that you have the Scripting Runtime referenced in the Tools>Project>References menu.   Secondly, I have understood that you have more than one document so this lot does everything in a folder.

I have just assumed, for this example, that the folder name is fixed.  In Real Life you can modify the code to select the folder and then modify the code to go through sub-folders, but this is (a) a quick hack and (b) out of scope.

```
Public Sub IncreaseVersionNumbers()

  ' Make sure that the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library is enabled in the Tools>Projects>References

  Dim sRootFolder As String
  Dim oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Dim oFolder As Scripting.Folder
  Dim oFile As Scripting.File

  sRootFolder = "C:\_Documents\VersionNumberTest\"   ' You can grab this by a Folder Selection dialog box instead

  Set oFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sRootFolder)
  For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If InStr(1, oFile.Name, ".doc", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      ProcessDocument (sRootFolder & oFile.Name)
    End If
  Next oFile

End Sub


Private Sub ProcessDocument(sDocument As String)

  Dim oDoc As Word.Document
  Dim oSection As Word.Section
  Dim oRange As Range
  Dim sHeaderText As String


  On Error Resume Next
  Set oDoc = Documents.Open(sDocument)

  For Each oSection In oDoc.Sections

    Set oRange = oSection.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
      ProcessHeaderRange oRange
    End If

    Set oRange = oSection.Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range
    If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
      ProcessHeaderRange oRange
    End If

    Set oRange = oSection.Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range
    If Not oRange Is Nothing Then
      ProcessHeaderRange oRange
    End If

  Next oSection

  oDoc.Close wdSaveChanges

End Sub


Private Sub ProcessHeaderRange(oRange As Range)

  Dim sText As String, sNewText As String
  Dim nPosn As Long, nStart As Long, nEnd As Long
  Dim sVersion As String, nVersion As Long


  sText = oRange.Text & " "

  nPosn = InStr(1, sText, "Version", vbTextCompare)
  If nPosn > 0 Then
    nStart = InStr(nPosn, sText, " ")
    If nStart > 0 Then
      nStart = nStart + 1
      nEnd = InStr(nStart, sText, " ")
      If nEnd > 0 Then
        sVersion = Mid$(sText, nStart, nEnd - nStart)
        nVersion = Val(sVersion)
        nVersion = nVersion + 1

        sNewText = Left$(sText, nStart - 1) & Trim$(Str$(nVersion)) & " " & Right$(sText, Len(sText) - nEnd)
        sNewText = Left$(sNewText, Len(sNewText) - 1)
        oRange.Text = sNewText
      End If
    End If
  End If

End Sub
```

This is, as I say, a quick hack so it may not work perfectly but, as always, have backups!

This works by going through each of the three possible headers in each possible section of the document.  And if it finds a header in a section then it does what you say.

And this version does go above single digit version numbers.  But it's a quick hack, as I say and so needs extra work to make it really bullet-proof.  Having said that, it's a reasonable start I would think.

Hope that this helps,

Malc

Comment: I didn't try yours, will give it a shot sometime and see if it works, but @macropod answer worked perfectly so i accepted his.

Comment: The answer provided by macropod should be good enough.  In a lot of ways it's more elegant than mine and if I were to do this again there's aspects of his that I would use.